# TinyMCE HTML Encode Backslash

Tags: javascript, tinymce

so my question is similar to the one found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/54398/how-can-i-stop-tinymce-from-converting-my-html-entities-to-characters?newreg=a76d1ec92cba4bc5b83a56d16b3e2768), following the example there i am trying to force Tiny MCE to encode backslashes......

currently all i am doing to test this is setting a break point on the page for the following line

```
tinymce.init( init );
```

then i run the following in the console

```
init.entities += ",92,#92"; init.entity_encoding = "named";
```

I see the values update in the init object but my \ is not converted....

not really sure what i am missing......

Answer (score 1):

finally figured out a way to approach this......

```
tinyMCE.init({
    setup: function(ed) 
    {
        ed.onGetContent.add(function(ed, o) {
            // Replaces all a characters with b characters
            o.content = o.content.replace(/\\/g, "&#92;");
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In newer versions (4.x and later) the code snippet should look like this:

```
setup: function (editor) {
    editor.on('GetContent', function (e) {
        //character encoding for backslash
        e.content = e.content.replace(/\\/g, "&#92;");
     });
}
```